# How can I use SUM(ABOVE) as part of a longer formula in Microsoft Word?

Tags: ms-word, formulas

I have a table like so:

```
Task 1  |   $59,700
Task 2  |   $59,700
Task 3  |   $59,700
10% Off |   $xx,xxx
-------------------
     Total: $xx,xxx
```

I'd like to use formulas in Word to calculate this.

For the first value, I'm using `=SUM(ABOVE)*0.10` I would expect this to yield $17,910.

For the second value, I'm using `=SUM(ABOVE)-C5` I'd expect this to yield $161,190.

Unfortunately, the first value and second value both yield $179,100 and I'm not exactly sure why.  Appreciate any help and thanks for reading.

Comment: Did you select the cells with the {=} formulas in and press F9 to update the results? (If you entered { +SUM(ABOVE) } in each cell in the first place they would show $179,100 until you did that). BTW, [ms-word] is probably a better tag to use for future Microsoft Word questions than [word].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the discount use `=SUM(ABOVE) * -0.1` to give you a negative discount.  Then use `=SUM(ABOVE)` by itself for total.  Numbers work out as expected.

[image]

[image]